# TDD. Как начать?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, шаблоны-проектирования

Я новичок в программирование на C# и хочу освоить разработку программ через тестирование. Читаю книги, форумы, смотрю видео, но везде пока то что я видел или читал идет показ примера в начале, не доходя даже до полной реализации хотя бы одного класса. Глаза видят, мозг вроде понимает, но руки не делаю). Не могу заставить себя не смотреть на весь проект в целом. Подскажите может есть где доходчивое ПОЛНОЕ объяснение как разробатывать через тестирование хотя бы на простом примере, например блога (User, Post, Comments) с полной реализацией хоть одного класса. Просто понято что разделаем зависимости, создаем api приложения но когда доходишь до конкретного примера где данные берутся из вне, не понятно как это тестировать и нужно ли вообще.

Придумал себе простой пример:

- 1.Загрузить текстовой файл employee.txt (в котором находят 
     строки с информацией о сотрудниках 
     id~имя~фамилия~отчество).
- 2.Загрузить тектовой файл deparment.txt (в котором находят 
     строки с информацией в каком отделе
     какой сотрудник idEmployee~название
     отдела).
- 3.Распарсить строки файла employee.txt.
- 4.Распарсить строки файла deparment.txt.
- 5.Проверить в бд изменения и занести (новый сотрудник, поменялась фамилия 
     у существуещего, поменялся отдел у 
     сотрудника).
- 6.Изменения вывести в консоль.

Сижу туплю не могу понять с чего начать именно разрабатывая через тестирование?

Comment: Подождите-подождите, вы сначала освойте обыкновенное программирование, а потом уж TDD. Суть TDD проста: вы вначале пишете тест к коду, а потом добавляете код класса/классов, следя, чтобы в конце-концов тест компилировался, запускался и завершался успешно. Для этого, понятно, надо уметь просто написать код, обычным образом.

Comment: Могу порекомендовать статью:  [Модульное тестирование][1]


  [1]: http://www.rsdn.ru/article/testing/UnitTesting.xml

Comment: @VladD вспомнилась инструкция по применению XP (не TDD) к проектированию парашюта. Сначала надо проверить, а нужна ли вообще эта работа -- сбросить испытателя без парашюта. Разбился -- можно двигаться дальше.

Comment: @alexlz: А что, правильный подход! Вдруг нужная функциональность есть уже «из коробки»? :-D

Помните классический [:|||||:] про математика, которому нужно вскипятить кастрюлю воды?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне когда-то очень помогла [книга](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1501671/) (практическое применение ТДД в проектах с примерами и советами - язык НЕ с#, но для понимания это неважно). Самое сложное было заставлять себя писать тесты перед кодом, а также смотреть на процесс разработки с другой стороны. Что касается тестирования, как такового, то для меня фаворитом среди книг является [эта](http://habrahabr.ru/post/136049/). Как правильно заметили в комментариях, для того, чтобы успешно применять модульное тестирование необходимо предварительно освоить выбранную технологию.

Comment: Экстремальное программирование? Перефразируя Высоцкого: "Но Крайслер, обули Крайслер... Каюсь, каюсь, каюсь..."

Comment: Не очень понял смысл того, что вы пытались донести цитатой Высоцкого. Можно "по простому"?

Comment: Я не знаком с экстремальным программированием и, соответственно, не могу судить, кто круче -- Кент Бек или Сергей Мавроди. Просто в конце 20го века был проект C3 (Crysler Comprehencive Compensation System -- если буквы не перепутал). Он начинался без XP, но через несколько месяцев его возглавил К.Бек. Проект окончился ничем -- "великий пук". Крайслер получил дырочку от бублика, а XP'еры написали несколько книг и кучу статей на тему "Круче XP -- только варёные яйца". Больше проектов такого масштаба у XP'еров не было.

Comment: Ничего не знаю о подобной статистике, но мне данный подход нравится, да и не только мне... Вы пропагандируете его непригодность, сравнивая с Мавроди, или просто бесит пафос вокруг него?

Comment: @alexlz да занятная была история, помню как нам морочили голову в универе этим XP

Comment: @wind насчёт TDD конкретно ничего сказать не могу -- не пробовал. Но вот XP вообще -- дикая смесь прописных истин (кто бы с ними спорил) и откровенного бреда.

Comment: @alexlz Хм, а у Фаулера написано ровно противоположное по поводу `C3` (http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/C3.html). Хотя, допускаю, что это может быть просто хитрой манипуляцией словами, дабы продолжать толкать `XP` в массы.

Comment: Любопытная дискуссия развернулась в комментах =)

Comment: http://www.avocallc.com/downloads/ExtremeProgramming.pdf

Ну и довольно злобная сказка на эту тему: http://www.softwarereality.com/lifecycle/xp/emperors_new_code.jsp

A young Java programmer from London, who was not afraid and could only see things as his eyes showed them to him, put up a small website with a contrary opinion.

"Emperor's process of DesignAfterFirstTesting is DAFT," he said. "ConstantRefactoringAfterProgramming is CRAP", he said. "The whole thing is a bunch of daft crap, actually".

Comment: @Котик а что у Фаулера написано противоположное? Что проект был успешно завершён? Так ведь нет там того. Проект был закрыт. Было причиной закрытия приобретение Крайслера Даймлером или отчаяние руководства ходом работ -- уже неважно. На полном объёме данных (кажется 84тыс) программы никогда не запускались. 10тыс на тестах (ну вроде у Кеефера говорится, что ещё 20тыс они могли потянуть -- не помню). Но не 84тыс.

 In particular the entry in Wikipedia is misleading and incomplete, much of its comments seem to be based on a paper from from a determined XP critic whose sources are unclear. :)))

Comment: Давайте-ка вброшу... Вот ещё классика про TDD vs. мозги: http://devgrind.com/2007/04/25/how-to-not-solve-a-sudoku/

Answer (score 3):

Простой, понятный, интересный пример использования метода TDD (а не средств тестирования!), подробно и по шагам - http://www.slideshare.net/amritayan/test-driven-development-in-c

Читал статьи, смотрел видео, но ничего лучше не нашел. Повторил все действия и сразу все стало на свои места. Это как езда на велосипеде. Нельзя прочитать книжку "Как ездить на велосипеде" и поехать. Надо сесть и поехать. И падать. Я до сих пор "падаю" (сбиваюсь на обычный стиль программирования). Но уже реже. Потом "держать равновесие" станет привычкой.